# IllegalArgumentException when trying to access a JNA function

Tags: java, jna

I am very new to JNA, and have a requirement of sending data to a legacy C system through Socket Connection from a Java System.
I have been provided with .dll and a .h file.

I have to access a function in C system with .h file definition.

I loaded the .dll and when i access the function in dll i get IllegalArgumentException

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arg arg = new Arg();
    ExampleDLL exampleDLL = ExampleDLL.INSTANCE;
    System.out.println(exampleDLL.someFunctionInDLL(arg));
}

public interface ExampleDLL extends Library {
    ExampleDLL INSTANCE = (ExampleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("exampleDLL.dll", ExampleDLL.class);

    int someFunctionInDLL(Arg arg);
}

public class Arg {
    public Byte[] var1 = new Byte[9];
    public Byte[] var2 = new Byte[5];
    // Getters and Setters....
}
```

From.h file:

```
typedef struct
{   
    char var1[9];   
    char var2[5];                   
}Arg;

int someFunctionInDLL(Arg *dr);
```

I think i have loaded the dll successfully but when i try to access the dll function :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type com.*.*.*.Arg at parameter 0 of function someFunctionInDLL
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Kind of stuck on this for some time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You are getting the error because the argument your function is expecting is a pointer, but you are providing it a full Java class.

```
int someFunctionInDLL(Arg *dr);
```

The `Arg` class you defined should be a [`Structure`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.3.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html).  By default, JNA converts a `Strcuture` to its pointer (`Structure.ByReference`) when used as a function argument, and that's precisely what you want to happen here. You should be able to fix your code by making `Arg` extend `Structure`.

Also, your mapping of bytes to the boxed `Byte` object is wrong: you need the primitive `byte` instead.  So this should work (you'll need to add `@FieldOrder` annotation as well):

```
public class Arg extends Structure {
    public byte[] var1 = new byte[9];
    public byte[] var2 = new byte[5];
}
```